# django run another class-based view (CBV) in a CBV?

Tags: django, django-views, django-class-based-views

so I have a CBV (A), CBV (B), and a url like

```
regex=r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/(?P<app>[-\w]+)'
```

I want to read in the slug and app parameters with (A) and then based on those, redirect it to an appropriate CBV, possible (B).  I don't want to redirect the user with HttpResponseRedirect or anything like that, but instead basically run another CBV as if it were the one being called.  How do I run another CBV, like (B), directly/internally from a CBV (A)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can call it that way:

```
class CBViewA(View):
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if kwargs['slug'] = "some slug":
            return CBViewB.as_view()(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return super(CBViewA, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: where in CBViewA would I call this and what/when/where do I return?