# Django class-based views: Invoking (forwarding to) a different class-based view

Tags: python, django

With Django functional views, it is very simple to invoke a different view function in order to "forward" a request to a different view. (The django codebase sometimes does this in its admin views.) You simply call the function and return the result.

for example:

```
def change_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
  if 'save_as_new' in request.GET:
    return add_view(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Its also easy enough to forward from a functional view to a Class-based view:

```
def change_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
  if 'save_as_new' in request.GET:
    return AddView.as_view()(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

However, I'm confused as to the proper or best way to conditionally invoke or forward to a second class-based view from a first class-based view, based on the existence or value of a url (GET) param or, alternatively, on the value of one of the args or kwargs from the url conf. Note that I'm not at all interested in doing a redirect here.

Comment: yeah looks like the answer... too bad its not search friendly! I just edited its title to include "class-based view" and not just CBV

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
class CBViewA(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'save_as_new' in request.GET:
            return AddView.as_view()(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

[django run another class-based view (CBV) in a CBV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16232072/django-run-another-cbv-in-a-cbv)

Comment: any particular reason you override `get` instead of `dispatch` like the referenced question?

Comment: @BenRoberts i think it more appropriate. Dispatch method is used just to redirect to post or get according to request data...

Comment: Above code results in `AttributeError`. First argument of `get` method should be `self`: `def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):`.